# Syntax issue with variable-length arguments assignment

Tags: java, arguments

I am trying to write a Java program that will calculate the product of a series of integers that are passed to method product using a variable-length argument list. The method must be tested with several calls, each with a different number of arguments.

I have written the code to the best of my understanding but cannot get it to compile without errors, and cannot grasp what I am doing wrong. I suspect I have something out of order, but just can't figure out what and am hoping for some advice. This is part of an assignment for my Java development class at school.

```
public class VLArgs 
{
    //calculates the product
    public static int product(int...numbers) 
    {

        int product = 1;

        //multiplies the integers
        for (int number:numbers) 
        {
            product *= number;
        }
        return product;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        int a = 1;
        int b = 2;
        int c = 3;
        int d = 4;
        int e = 5;

        //displays the values   
        System.out.printf(“a = %d, b = %d, c = %d, d = %d, e = %d\n”,
        a, b, c, d, e);

        //calls the product of the values with a different number of arguments in each call

         System.out.printf(“The product of a and b is: %d\n”,product(a, b));

         System.out.printf(“The product of a, b and c is: %d\n”,product(a, b, c));

         System.out.printf(“The product of a, b, c and d is: %d\n”, product(a, b, c, d));

         System.out.printf(“The product of a, b, c, d and e is: %d\n”, product(a, b, c, d, e));
     }
}
```

The main error I am receiving is:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
>   at VLArgs.main(VLArgs.java:31)

And all of the errors within that are syntax errors (about 35).

Comment: Your code and the logic seems to be perfectly correct. The one issue seems to be in `“`. Just change it to `"` and it'll work. I know this sounds silly, but different compiles interpret Unicode symbols differently. You can see this. https://ideone.com/THqqLa

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem in your print statement. its using some unknown character formatting.

I have updated the code as per your requirement. match it with your code and you will understand it.

For any issue comment on this answer.

```
public class VLArgs {
//calculates the product
    public static int product(int... numbers) {

        int product = 1;

//multiplies the integers
        for (int number : numbers) {
            product *= number;
        }
        return product;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int a = 1;
        int b = 2;
        int c = 3;
        int d = 4;
        int e = 5;

//displays the values   

        System.out.printf("The product of a and b is: %d%n", product(a, b));

        System.out.printf("The product of a, b and c is: %dn", product(a, b, c));

        System.out.printf("The product of a, b, c and d is: %dn", product(a, b, c, d));

        System.out.printf("The product of a, b, c, d and e is: %dn", product(a, b, c, d, e));

    }
}
```

Comment: This was exactly the problem, and by changing out the quotes manually in the IDE it now compiles and runs.